# spring controller returns 404 but restcontroller ok

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/html")
    public String retHtml() {
        return "<html></html>";
    }
}
```

I have a very simple Controller. I can access the api when it has the annotation of `@RestController`, but it returns http status of 404 when the annotation becomes `@Controller`.

What could be the possible reasons for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You are getting a 404 not found error because when you annotate your java class as @Controller, **Spring expects a view path to be returned in controller methods but you are returning <"html"><"html"> which is not a path**. Second The code syntax is wrong. Your return type does not match what you really return (<"html"><"html">).
If you want to implement a Spring MVC controller just replace The return type with String and return a view path; Else, If you want to have RestApi, Annotate the class with @RestController and return a ResponseEntity object.

Comment: The return type was a typo. It is `String` and I have fixed it. Can you be more specific on the concept of `view path `? Is it the path of the html file?

Comment: @SeakyLone the view path is the name of your HTML or JSP file in spring boot. the view resolver will find the file using its name. in spring boot your view files are under the resources/templates. But in spring and web deploy types they are under WEB-INF dir.

Comment: What if I want to return just a string instead of an html file? I am able to do this by copying bytes to `httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()`. Is there a more elegent way?

Comment: Just annotate the class as @RestController. This way the Spring will detect that you are returning data rather than a view path.